# Should I use XCC insertContent or xdmp:document-insert?

Tags: marklogic

Which is better in terms of performance? Can I do batching when using `xdmp:document-insert`?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that `xdmp:document-insert` is XQuery. So you might have to learn something new.

Performance should be about the same. You can batch calls to `xdmp:document-insert` using a sequence of expressions, a FLWOR, or any other valid XQuery.

```
xdmp:document-insert('test/a', <test/>),
xdmp:document-insert('test/a', <test/>),
...
```

An equivalent FLWOR expression might be:

```
for $i in ('a', 'b')
return xdmp:document-insert(concat('test/', $i), <test/>)
```

Either way all the updates will commit as a single ACID transaction. If that isn't what you want, take a look at http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2013/06/21/introduction-to-multi-statement-transactions/